# Laravel 5.4 required if validation issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have 2 fields, accepts_usd and price_usd.

For price usd I have a validation rule:

```
'price_usd'=>'integer|required_if:accepts_usd,1',
```

And for accepts_usd:

```
'accepts_usd'=>'boolean|required',
```

When I want to store data if I set accepts_usd to false it still asks for price_usd.

whats the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From laravel docs:
required_if:anotherfield,value,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Value is not an actual value, its another validation rule.

Answer (score 5):

you need to change your code to

```
'price_usd'=>'integer|required_if:accepts_usd,==,1',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `'price_usd'=>'integer|required_if:accepts_usd,==,1',`

As mentioned in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) :

> required_if:anotherfield,value,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the
>   anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in Laravel 8. So I add the validation rules as follows.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    'is_public_template' => 'boolean',

    'logo' => ['bail', 'nullable', 'required_if:is_public_template,true', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'],
    'public_template_name' => ['bail', 'nullable', 'required_if:is_public_template,true', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    'description' => ['bail', 'nullable', 'required_if:is_public_template,true', 'min:8', 'max:255'],
    'active' => 'boolean',
]);
```

In my case, `is_public_template` is a boolean type, so I add `bail` and `nullable` rule in front of `required_if`.

So it is working fine.

**Side note:-** you should also cast the boolean field's value otherwise they will return as a normal string like "1" or "0".